# Understanding numpy condition on array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't understand some code from Kaggle's solution.

Here is an example of the data:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
```

The goal is to extract an array with only the female, and they do it like this:

```
# data contains all the passengers
women_only_stats = data[0::,4] == "female"
females_data = data[women]
print(data[women][0]) # Will print the first women of the dataset of only women.
```

I understand that `women_data_only` will be an array of `True` and `False` which is the result of the evaluation of the expression `data[0::,4] == "female"`. 
 
What I do not understand is why data[women] is an array of only women? 

 
How is `numpy` evaluate that?

Comment: This epxlains it: [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)

Comment: Search for "boolean indexing"

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it works:

`women_only_stats = data[0::,4] == "female"` will create a **mask** (array of `booleans`) for the indices of your dataframe.

When passed to `data`, the mask will do a **projection** on the samples where  `women_only_stats` is `True`, thus keeping only women.

You can have a look [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) about mask indexing.

Comment: Thanks! So in the original dataframe, each 'female' will be replaced (overlayed) by the value `True` or `False`, and the resulting array will only keep the rows where the value of the 4th column is `True`. Am I right by saying this?

Comment: It is not replacing it. It does not change the dataframe. It creates an array of booleans, called **mask**. Then when you pass this mask to your dataframe (i.e. when you index by this mask) it will make a projection on the samples where  `mask == True`. Returning then a dataframe where samples are only women.

Comment: Ahhhh ! Get it!!
Thanks a lot for this explanation, and for the time you took for me.